# Numpy where function over second dimension of Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have an Array X with the dimension DxN and an Array Y with dimension 1xN. Y only contains 1's and -1's. Now I want a new Array with every element of X for which Y has a 1. I know I have to use a np.where() function but how do I use the mask for the N-dimension of X and not the D-dimension. If I do it like this I get an error because N>D. As an output I want a new Array with dimension DxM with M<N.

```
import numpy as np


X = np.array([
   [-17, -10,  -3, 3, 13, -9],
   [-17,  -8,   2, 5, 9, -8],
   [-15, -12,  -6, 3, 13, -10],
   [-11,  -5,  -1,  1, 7, -36]])
Y = np.array([-1, -1,  1, -1])
```

I want to get the third element of X into a new Array, because Y[2]=1:

```
X_new = np.array([-15, -12,  -6, 3, 13, -10])
```

But I use the np.where() function wrong, I just don't know how to do it properly. Afterwards I want to do the same for Y==-1

```
X_new = X[np.where(Y==1)]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to show a sample of your input data and expected output to make a [mcve] so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: Get the `Y==1` part right first, then apply `np.where`, and **look** at the result.  It should be a tuple of one or more arrays.  Do those arrays look like the right ones to index `X`.  In other words, test the expression step by step.  This **is** python, evaluate it and test it as such.

Comment: Do you really need `np.where` to do that? `X_new = X[Y==1,:]` is a valid alternative.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with what you tried?

```
In [104]: X[np.where(Y==1)]
Out[104]: array([[-15, -12,  -6,   3,  13, -10]])
In [105]: X[np.where(Y==-1)]
Out[105]: 
array([[-17, -10,  -3,   3,  13,  -9],
       [-17,  -8,   2,   5,   9,  -8],
       [-11,  -5,  -1,   1,   7, -36]])
```

Without the `nonzero`:

```
In [107]: X[Y==1]
Out[107]: array([[-15, -12,  -6,   3,  13, -10]])
```

The tuple of indices where it is true:

```
In [108]: np.nonzero(Y==1)
Out[108]: (array([2]),)
```

Indexing with a scalar 2 does give a 1d array, as opposed to 2d

```
In [109]: X[2]
Out[109]: array([-15, -12,  -6,   3,  13, -10])
```

But the `-1` case will still be 2d.